# Google Play Console prevent production is released automatically

Tags: android

Is there any method for preventing automatically roll out in Google Play Console?

In the App Store, I can select whether I permit automatically release by App store after review or release manually.

I read this [docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9543912?hl=en) But timed publishing doesn't match my need.

Also, I traveled several features in play console. But I cannot find any functions for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the new Play Console, we can use **Managed Publish** in **Publishing overview** tab.

[image: Play console preview]

Answer (score 2):

I found you cannot set it to 0%, if you do so the button to continue will be disabled.

What did work was setting it to a percentage that is higher than zero, but still results in 0 matching users, e.g **0.001%**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you push your **`APK file`** or **`Android app bundle`** to the production channel and fill up all the necessary fields, you have the option to setup the **`rollout amount`**.

If you want to control that process, then simply set it to **`0`**. It will not get released unless you **`increase`** it.

Comment: can tou attack any image guide?